# Как убрать ложные срабатывания с input

Tags: reactjs

Есть input для поиска товаров по названию
Есть обработка нажатий `onChangeSearch` в нем мы убираем все лишнее, оставляя только нужные нам символы
Есть функция `load` она отправлять запрос на сервер с текстом из поля(Для тестов, сейчас там просто вывод в консоль)
Проблема заключается в том, что при вводе любого запрещенного символа у нас вызывается функция `load` и идет запрос на сервер, возможно ли сделать вызов функции `load` только при условии, что введен нужный нам символ?

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     filter_search: ''
    }
    this.onChangeSearch = this.onChangeSearch.bind(this);
  }
  onChangeSearch(e) {
    let regexp = /[^a-zа-яё,._\-\/=\!\?0-9\s]/gi;
    let value = e.target.value;
    value = value.replace(/^\s/, '');
    value = value.replace(/  /, ' ');
    value = value.replace(regexp, '');
    value = value.substr(0, 25);
    this.setState({
      filter_search: value
    });
    this.load();
  }
  load() {
   console.log('1');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          value = {this.state.filter_search}
          onChange = {this.onChangeSearch}
        /> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, не знаю на сколько это правильное решение, но свою функцию выполняет
В чем суть: добавил новую переменную `filter_search_old`, добавил в `onChangeSearch` проверку на совпадение значения в переменной `filter_search_old` и полученного значения из `input` если они не совпадают, мы вызываем функцию `load` и записываем новое значение в `filter_search_old`, если они совпали, значит текст в поле не изменился.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     filter_search: '',
      filter_search_old: ''
    }
    this.onChangeSearch = this.onChangeSearch.bind(this);
  }
  onChangeSearch(e) {
    let regexp = /[^a-zа-яё,._\-\/=\!\?0-9\s]/gi;
    let value = e.target.value;
    value = value.replace(/^\s/, '');
    value = value.replace(/  /, ' ');
    value = value.replace(regexp, '');
    value = value.substr(0, 25);
    this.setState({
      filter_search: value
    });
    if(this.state.filter_search_old != value) {
      this.load();
      this.setState({
        filter_search_old: value
      });
    }
  }
  load() {
   console.log('1');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          value = {this.state.filter_search}
          onChange = {this.onChangeSearch}
        /> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```